# Mocking EF6 with validation that occurs on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I found a decent article to get me started on unit testing my Entity Framework-based application using Moq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

This issue I'm having is that the `SaveChanges` method of the Mock does not appear to trigger the `ValidateEntity` method like it normally would. None of the validation settings I configured in the `EntityTypeConfiguration` are being thrown as a `DbEntityValidationException`.

For example, my `AddRoles_Fails_For_Empty_Name` tests to make sure that the service cannot add a role with an empty name. Either the `IsRequired()` configuration is not being applied, or the `ValidateEntity` method is not being called. I should mention that it works correctly if I use the actual context in the web app.

I've included some of my relevant unit testing, DbContext, and Service code below.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Are there any known issues or workarounds?

**Role DB Map**

```
public class RoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        ToTable("bm_Roles");
        HasKey(r => r.Id);
        Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100).HasIndex(new IndexAttribute("UX_Role_Name") { IsUnique = true });
        Property(r => r.Description).HasMaxLength(500);
    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class BlueMoonContext : DbContext, IBlueMoonContext
{
    public BlueMoonContext() : base("name=BlueMoon")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(BlueMoonContext).Assembly);
    }

    public void MarkAsModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        entity.ThrowIfNull("entity");
        Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added || entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            // Perform validations that require database lookups
            if (entityEntry.Entity is Role)
            {
                ValidateRole((Role)entityEntry.Entity, result);
            }
            else if (entityEntry.Entity is User)
            {
                ValidateUser((User)entityEntry.Entity, result);                    
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void ValidateRole(Role role, DbEntityValidationResult result)
    {
        if (role.Name.HasValue() && !Roles.NameAvailable(role.Name, role.Id))
        {
            result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("Name", "Already in use"));
        }
    }

    private void ValidateUser(User user, DbEntityValidationResult result)
    {
        if (user.UserName.HasValue() && !Users.UserNameAvailable(user.UserName, user.Id))
        {
            result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("UserName", "Already in use"));
        }
        if (user.Email.HasValue() && !Users.UserNameAvailable(user.UserName, user.Id))
        {
            result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("Email", "Already in use"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Account Service**

```
public class AccountService : BaseService, IAccountService
{
    private IPasswordHasher _passwordHasher;

    public AccountService(IBlueMoonContext context, IPasswordHasher passwordHasher) : base(context)
    {
        _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
    }

    public ServiceResult CreateRole(Role role)
    {
        role.ThrowIfNull("role");
        Context.Roles.Add(role);
        return Save();
    }

    // Copied from base service class
    protected ServiceResult Save()
    {
        var result = new ServiceResult();
        try
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException validationException)
        {

            foreach (var validationError in validationException.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var error in validationError.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    result.AddError(error.ErrorMessage, error.PropertyName);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountServiceTests : BaseTest
{
    protected Mock<MockBlueMoonContext> _context;
    private IAccountService _accountService;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _context = new Mock<BlueMoonContext>();

        var data = new List<Role>
        {
            new Role { Id = 1, Name = "Super Admin" },
            new Role { Id = 2, Name = "Catalog Admin" },
            new Role { Id = 3, Name = "Order Admin" }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var roleSet = CreateMockSet<Role>(data);
        roleSet.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(ids => data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == (int)ids[0]));

        _context.Setup(m => m.Roles).Returns(roleSet.Object);
        // _context.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges()).Returns(0);
        _accountService = new AccountService(_context.Object, new CryptoPasswordHasher());
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddRole_Fails_For_Empty_Name()
    {
        var role = new Role { Id = 4, Name = "" };

        var result = _accountService.CreateRole(role);
        Assert.False(result.Success);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveChanges` is a `virtual` method which means you invoke a fake method....

You can create your mock `CallBase = true`, but it is not a good idea(it miss the idea of UT):

```
_context = new Mock<BlueMoonContext>(){ CallBase = true };
```

The above code will use the real implementation of `BlueMoonContext` for any method/property which is not explicitly setup.

`RoleMap` is responsible for your DB stracture, you should test it as a part of integration test(with DB).

In my opinion you should create an integration tests to verify the integrity(for example; cover `RoleMap`) with your DB, And create a UT using the `Throw` setup to cover the catch section(it's a part of your **unit**):

```
_contest.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges())
          .Throws(new DbEntityValidationException());
```

**Edit to answer the OP question in the comment**

no, you don't have to separate the built in validation, you have to create another test(integration test). In this test you'll verify the validation behaviour: insert an illegal entity, expect that exception will raise(using `ExpectedExceptionAttribute`) and then verify that the DB is empty... to apply this behaviour use this pattern:

```
try
{
    \\...
    \\try to commit
}
catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    \\do some validation, then: 
    throw;\\for ExpectedExceptionAttribute
}
```

I looked over the api of `EntityTypeConfiguration`, I didn't saw any contact which allows to UT the rules(unless you use tools like `MsFakes`, `TypeMock Isolator` there is no way to verify the `ToTable/HasKey/Property` was called). The class is being in used inside `EntityFramework`(which is a part of the BCL) in the integration test you don't have to verify that `EntityFramework` work properly, you are going to verify that your custom rules was integrated and works as you expect(In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809530/how-to-unit-test-textrenderer-drawtext-method-in-c-sharp/31899094#31899094) you can read the reason not to test a BCL classes).

So use `Moq` in the UTs of `AccountService`. Create an integration tests for `BlueMoonContext` and `RoleMap`(without `Moq`).

By the way @LadislavMrnka offer an [interesting way to test(integration test)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459163/4332059) `EntityTypeConfiguration`

Comment: While I agree that the RoleMap is indeed responsible for the DB structure, it also allows me to enforce simple validation constraints like `Required` and `StringLength`. In order to "properly" unit test, do I need to strip away the built-in validation and put it in it's own layer? Or do I do away with the Moq and just create another concretenimplementation of `IBlueMoonContext` that does not hit the database for testing?

Comment: So, what I ended up doing was separating the validation from the `SaveChanges()` method. I did this by setting `Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` in the constructor. Then I created a light-weight entity validator class that wraps the DataAnnotations `Validator` class and inject it into my services.